# Как вызвать перегруженный метод в потоке std::thread?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

Я новичок в потоковой обработке, я пытаюсь передать перегруженные методы в std::thread, как показано в примере ниже

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
class thA
{
    public:
    int fun(int a, int b, int c)  
    {
        return a + b + c;
    }
    int fun()
    {
        cout << "Hello World" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
};
int main()
{
    thA a;
    
    thread classAAA ( &thA::fun, &a );
    classAAA.detach();
    while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

но программа не компилируется и выдает ошибку:

```
main.cpp:21:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(, thA*)’
   21 |     thread classAAA ( &thA::fun, &a );
```

Есть ли способ вызвать перегруженные методы в потоке?

Comment: Чтобы вызвать перегруженный метод следует выбрать конкретную перегрузку. Также присутствует ошибка - вызов `detach();`

Comment: Я знаю, что надо выбрать конкретную, но как это сделать не знаю, потому и спрашиваю. В чем ошибка, вызвал поток и оторвал его?

Comment: Для этого необходимо привести получаемый указатель к нужному типу. После вызова `detach();` поток продолжит работу. Это 1) утеря контроля над ресурсами 2) после выхода из `main` поток остается с висящим указателем.

Comment: На этот указатель не выделялось никакого места, это просто указатель на функцию. Вы что-то путаете. Если бы на него выделялось место, то да это висячий указатель, место которого на отчистить, а так это просто указатель, после завершения программы система сама его отчистит.

Comment: Я имел ввиду указатель на объект `a`, у которого вызывается эта фунуция.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну укажите конкретный тип вызываемой функции-члена...

```
using func = int (thA::*)(void);
thread classAAA( func(&thA::fun), a);
```

См. https://ideone.com/b6LkPf

[Для второй функции](https://ideone.com/UWC4es):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

volatile int run = true;

using namespace std;
class thA
{
    public:
    int fun(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        cout << "Farewell World" << endl;
        run = false;
        return a + b + c;
    }
    int fun()
    {
        cout << "Hello World" << endl;
        run = false;
        return 0;
    }
};
int main()
{
    thA a;

    using func = int (thA::*)(int,int,int);

    thread classAAA( func(&thA::fun), a, 0, 1, 2);

    classAAA.detach();
    while(run){}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А другую функцию как вызвать?

Comment: Да точно так же, только аргументы не забыть передать: https://ideone.com/UWC4es

Comment: А можешь написать будь добр, а то ideone у меня не открывается. Попробовал написать так:using func = int (thA::*)(int,int,int);
    thread classAAA ( func(&thA::fun), aa, 1,2,3); Но не заработало

Comment: Спасибо большое за решение.

Comment: Чтение/запись одной переменной (`run`) из разных потоков без синхронизации. [Поведение приведённой программы не определено](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368274/how-to-declare-and-use-one-writer-many-readers-one-process-simple-type-vari).

Comment: @wololo Вы смеетесь, да? Я для демонстрации, как вызвать нужную функцию, буду писать всю обвязку для нормальной работы? Тем более что как ни крути, а оно сработает в любом случае, как надо — задержав программу настолько, чтоб поток успел вывод сделать...